# Force correct separator on decimals

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

Trying to force a certain separator on a column which has decimal values but despite me formatting as `"# #0.00"` it always opens with a comma since those are my regional settings. Example code:

```
var decimalPattern = String.Format(@"# #0.00");

foreach (var dataColumn in columns)
{
    worksheet.Column(dataColumn.Ordinal + 1).Style.Numberformat.Format = decimalPattern;
}
```

columns is a list of datacolumns which are of the type decimal.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Have you tried modifying your current culture?

Comment: I've added a culture and the separator is based on the culture, I've only added the . for convenience in the example. I pass on the correct format depending on the culture info which I set before creating everything (think adding to the datatable etc).

Comment: What is the reason that you want Excel to display decimal values exactly the same on all machines, regarless of the regional settings? I one user is Dutch and the other is an American, why not let them decide (by modifying the regional settings) what they wanna see?

Comment: Most users have trouble opening a CSV file in Excel let alone change regional settings :). I just want to prevent wrong numbers being shown to the user. Users can select a different separator compared to their regional settings but this one will be ignored by Excel (probably won't happen a lot but I'd like to cover all users their requirements).

Comment: Are you exporting to an XLS(X)-file or CSV-file?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new [`CultureInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Globalization.CultureInfo(v=vs.110).aspx) object which suits your needs or modify it to suit your needs. Then set this CultureInfo as your default culture:

For example:

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("nl-NL"); // Uses a , for decimal seperation.
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
// From here on, all values which are converted to strings, are formatted using this culture.
```

Comment: I've done that which works fine but what I am trying to achieve is regardless in which region this file is opened it will always keep the specified separator. Now when I have a comma as separator and I change my computer settings to US settings the comma is automatically changed to a dot. This despite the cell having a custom format with the correct separator.

Comment: Which file? Your question is not mentioning any file. Are you exporting your results from your worksheet to an export file? I get the feeling I am hearing only part of the total problem.

Comment: My question has been edited it seems but I figured the Excel tag would be enough information. I'm exporting to Excel with the EpPlus library (this part got edited off of the title). So cells have a custom format with the specified format as in the example. But regardless of the specified separator it always opens the file based on the computer settings. I could have been more clear about this in my example too though, my apologies.

Comment: I am starting to understand. In that case you are talking about the workings of Excel, not C# or .NET or EPPlus. If Excel has a decimal value, he will ALWAYS format it using the computer settings. I can think of one workaround: Fill the excelsheet will correctly formatted strings. In that you are in control of the formatting and Excel simply diplays them as strings.